How can I optimize S3 writes to avoid throttling with Apache Iceberg?
I'm working with large datasets, writing to S3, and facing throttling issues (503 errors). Although we're using the Apache Iceberg table format, our challenge seems somewhat independent of Iceberg itself.
To mitigate this, we began partitioning our data by adding a key prefix immediately after the S3 bucket name, aiming to reduce throttling occurrences. Despite these efforts, our ingestion service still encounters 503 errors, leading me to question the efficacy of our prefix strategy.
Specifically, I'm curious about how S3 manages key prefix determination. Does it group keys by the path separator (slashes /), or does it evaluate prefixes character by character? Our method involves a hash function and base64 encoding, which frequently incorporates dashes (-) in the key prefixes, potentially affecting how data is categorized into throttling buckets. If the prefix grouping is done on a per-character basis, it might explain the continued throttling issues due to data being funneled into the same bucket.
Does anyone have insights into how S3's prefix grouping works in this context?
Here is how the files are showing right under my bucket at the root level;

See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHeTn9pHNKo&t=3219s
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3


Thanks for reaching out here.
To give a more precise answer, it would be good to know how you are writing to the Iceberg table.
One thing to check first is to make sure that the write.object-storage.enabled property is set to true. This will make sure the objects are distributed across the prefixes.
More fundamentally, it is good to look at the sizes of the Parquet files that you're writing. If you have CDC kind of workloads, and you have a lot of writers that write small Parquet files, that is going to be a problem. If a file is small, it will have to do several requests to write just a small portion of data, which increases the number of requests substantially.
For the read side of things. This is even more important since big data workloads are most likely to follow a write-once, and read-often pattern. It is important to make sure that the data is compacted periodically. This applies both to the Iceberg metadata that's stored in Avro, and the data files itself (most probably Parquet). Optimizing the metadata can be done through Spark using the rewrite_manifests procedure. This will combine small manifests into bigger ones that will reduce the number of requests when reading.. It is best to first run rewrite_data_files, then rewrite_manifests as mentioned above, and then rewrite_orphan_files.
If you don't want to care about this stuff, there are also commercial vendors such as Tabular that will make sure that your Iceberg tables are in pristine condition.
